# Redis connection index undefined

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

The following error is thrown whilst the application is trying to access the session:

```
Undefined index: redis

..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Database.php
 * Get a specific Redis connection instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return \Predis\ClientInterface
 */
public function connection($name = 'default')
{
    return $this->clients[$name ?: 'default'];
}
```

I have removed all the **Redis** references in my cache (changed to file) and session config files(changed to database), but to no avail.

And yea, the correct config files are being loaded.

Any thoughts, before i go all `rm testbed/*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by reinstalling laravel through composer and using the same old config files.

In fact, the `session.php` config file's `connection` parameter was set to `redis` and this is what caused the error. Setting it back to `null` fixed the issue.